# Dynamically changing Ruby-on-Rails variables in a view

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have the following `select_tag`.

```
<%= select_tag :days, options_for_select(["Monday", "Tuesday"]) %>
```

Somewhere, in the view I defined the following variable.

```
<% @day_of_week = "Monday" %>
```

And showed it :

```
<%= @day_of_week %>
```

I would like to dynamically change `@day_of week`, after a value is selected from the `select_tag`.

Comment: you should use javascript, it's all client side here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery for this.

Add this to the head of your html file (if you dont have jquery yet) :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Wrap your text like this to give it an id :

```
<div id="text_to_be_changed"><%= @day_of_week %></div>
```

Give a specific id to your SELECT tab (if #days does not work for some reason).

```
<%= select_tag :days, options_for_select(["Monday", "Tuesday"]), :id => "select_days" %>
```

Then add this unobtrusive JavaScript to the end of your view. 
Any change to the select#days will trigger a modification of div#text_to_be_changed's html.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_days').change(function() {
        $('#text_to_be_changed').html($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to display day user select from select tag?..
use unobtrusive JavaScript.its simple as that

```
$('#days').change(function() {
  $('#current_day').html(this.val());
});
```

where 'days' is id of select tag
and  'current_day' will be id of div where you wants to show selected day

Comment: I have added the javascript code inside a <script type=text/javascript>
 block, but when I reload the page it gives me the following error in my browser (Chrome): "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'change'"